# How do I show a hidden element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, triggers, show

```
<script>
$("#apick").click(
    function () {
        $("#answer").show("slow");
    }
);
</script>

<div id = "answer" style="display:none;" >
    Word is: <span id = "word"></span>
</div>

<a href="#" id = "apick" class="pick">Trigger!</a>
```

I'm trying to make the trying to make the link "Trigger" to show the div, answer, but its not working. Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subscription to the click event is supposed to run when the document is fully loaded.  Therefore you should wrap your setup code in a $() call.

```
$(function {
   // your setup code goes here
});
```

So your code becomes:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#apick").click(
        function () {
            $("#answer").show("slow");
        }
    );
});

</script>

<div id = "answer" style="display:none;" >
    Word is: <span id = "word"></span>
</div>

<a href="#" id = "apick" class="pick">Trigger!</a>
```

Comment: ...and you probably want `return false;` there, unless you want the browser to navigate to the '' anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<script>...</script>` tag after the link, so that the link actually exists when the jQuery code tries to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It'll work only if :

1. You load jQuery first
2. You make this script work when everything is ready

[Example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/2ggpW/1/)

```
<div id = "answer" style="display:none;" >
    Word is: <span id = "word"></span>
</div>

<a href="#" id = "apick" class="pick">Trigger!</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#apick").click(
    function () {
        $("#answer").show("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);
});
</script>
```